Unable to create Azure Storage Account even though I have free 200$ credit from microsoft
I keep getting this error while creating storage account. I am unable to debug it. any help will be really appreciated.
Error:
{
  "message": "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'MessagePort': function(J$){var z3;z3=this[P4t] + y9O;L_M.s_t();while(z3-=y9O){if(this[z3 - y9O] === J$){return s5D;}}return V3f;} could not be cloned.",
  "stack": "Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'MessagePort': function(J$){var z3;z3=this[P4t] + y9O;L_M.s_t();while(z3-=y9O){if(this[z3 - y9O] === J$){return s5D;}}return V3f;} could not be cloned.\n    at postMessage (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/AcuRKQe4PvBz.js:305:4304)\n    at Le (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/AcuRKQe4PvBz.js:227:5977)\n    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/AcuRKQe4PvBz.js:227:6268",
  "isError": true
}


Please edit to show your code and all other details. Right now it's just an error message with no other context. Not even clear that this is an Azure issue.

It's either a problem with your session or your browser.
Log out of the portal. Close all browser tabs. Relaunch browser, sign in to Portal and try again.
Failing that, try a different browser. Edge Chromium, Chrome and Firefox should work just fine.
Ensure your browser is up to date.
